# How to sort a multidimensional array by First Name in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

I'm just trying to sort a multidimensional array by firstName. I've been doing a lot of research and can't really find anything similar to my issue.

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lastName] => Mark
        [firstName] => White
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [lastName] => Brown
        [firstName] => Peter

[2] => Array
    (
        [lastName] => Paul
        [firstName] => Vo
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [lastName] => MCLwous
        [firstName] => Luis
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [lastName] => Zumilia
        [firstName] => Mario
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [lastName] => Carl
        [firstName] => Burns
    )
)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: @jszobody I have already looked at that one and can't really figure it out how to implemented on my task :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function which sorts arrays using a user-defined comparison function:

```
usort($array, function($v1, $v2) { return strcmp($v1['firstName'], $v2['firstName']); });
```

Or you can use [sorted](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#sortedsequence-reversed--false-key--null-cmp--null) function from [Nspl](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl):

```
use function \nspl\a\sorted;
$sorted = sorted($array, 'firstName');
```

Comment: @lhor Burlachenko Thanks so much!!

Comment: I really would recommend using Laravel Collections if you have access to them, they are super nice, and make for much cleaner code than using the raw php.

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged the question `laravel`, I'll give you an answer that uses that framework, specifically the methods available to you when using [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections):

`$sorted = collect($arr)->sortBy('firstName');`

Note, that will return a laravel `Collection`, rather than a php array.

If you then wanted the sorted data back out as a plain php array, you would add a call to `toArray` at the end:

`$sorted = collect($arr)->sortBy('firstName')->toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

First idea I have is to manually check each 'firstName' and keep firstName and userId in a separate dictionary. Then rearrange the elements on another empty array using the sorted dictionary (Sorting a dictionary by value or key is possible. I have seen answers to that). That's a quick answer. :)